# Create New Element Continually Following One After Another

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say that I have existing element in my array `[10, 20, 30]`, and I want the user to input an element, eg. the user inputs element `4`, so I want the output to become like this `[10, 4, 20, 4, 30]`.

But I only manage to get user to enter the element 10 times (like my array size), but I just want it to be entered once.

I don't know how to change "`score.size()`", that is 10 in size, to only one element, so I can get output like this `[10, 4, 20, 4, 30]`.

This is some of my coding:

```
ArrayList<Double> score = new ArrayList<Double>();

// (here I already set some elements in the array)

for (int i = 1; i <= score.size(); i += 2)
{ 
    System.out.println("Enter the element you want to add: ");
    double addedElement = in.nextDouble();

    score.add(i, addedElement);
}
System.out.println(score);
```

Comment: You ask the user _inside_ the loop. Of course, the user then gets asked several times. Move the statements that ask the user above the loop, so it gets executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `score.size()` in the loop as its size will increase as you add elements in the loop. Instead store the size in a local variable and then use that variable for the condition in the loop.

Change as follows:

```
        int n = score.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i ++) {

            System.out.println("Enter the element you want to add: ");
            Double addedElement = in.nextDouble();

            score.add(2*i+1, addedElement);
        }
```

This code will ask you for a number for each iteration. So, if you have an existing array of `[10,20,30]` and you enter `9` and `5` as input. Then you will get output as `[10,9,20,5,30]`.

If you want only a single number as an input then just move the input line before the loop.

```
        int n = score.size();
        System.out.println("Enter the element you want to add: ");
        Double addedElement = in.nextDouble();
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i ++) {
            score.add(2*i+1, addedElement);
        }
```

So, if you enter have an existing array of `[10,20,30]` and you enter `9` as input. Then you will get output as `[10,9,20,9,30]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here's the code that should do what Seelenvirtuose said.

```
List<Double> score = new ArrayList<Double>();

//Add the initial stuff
score.add((double)10);
score.add((double)20);
score.add((double)30);

//Get the input from the user
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
double d = in.nextDouble();

in.close();

//Loop through the list and add the input to the correct places
for(int i = 1; i < score.size(); i+= 2)
    score.add(i, d);

System.out.println(score);`
```

score.size() returns the amount of elements in the list, so in your example case, where the list contains initially 10, 20 and 30, your loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= score.size(); i += 2)
{ 
System.out.println("Enter the element you want to add: ");
double addedElement = in.nextDouble();

score.add(i, addedElement); 
}
```

goes like this:

1. i = 1, score.size() == 3. The user enters a number and it is added to place 1 in the list (between 10 and 20). i += 2.
2. i == 3, score.size() == 4. User enters another number and it goes to the place 3 (between 20 and 30). i += 2.
3. i == 5, score.size() == 5. User enters another number and it goes to the place 5 (after 30). i += 2.
4. i == 7, score.size() == 6. The loop ends.

The way you change the score.size() is by adding or removing elements. In your example case it should never go to 10. Hope this helps to understand.

Finally, if you are new to Java, note that an array (for example double[]) and a list (for example ArrayList) are very different things, even though they are used for similar purposes. You may want to google their differences, if you don't know.